# Declare a variable and return it in the same line C++

Tags: c++, return-value

I have code that does

```
if(x>5){
vector<int> a;
return a;
}
```

But i'm curious if theres a way to do this return in one line such like:

```
if(x>5){
return vector<int> a;
}
```

Comment: `return vector<int>();` ?

Comment: If the return type of your function is `vector<int>`, you can even just write `return {};`.

Comment: Ah the classic XY Problem.  You did not actually want to declare a variable, grasshopper.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will work as expected:

```
return vector<int>();
```

This creates an object and returns one at the same time. Since the object has not been created without any name, it is known as `anonymous object`.

Hence you can modify your code, without assigning a name to the variable, like this:

```
if(x>5){
return vector<int>();
}
```

Comment: Great thank you! Can using an anonymous object lead to issues or is it generally considered a safe practice?

Comment: Yes, as long as it follows the properties of a normal object, it is safe.

Comment: @zeltath if this answer helped you, please mark it as accepted so that it would help others with same query

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `vector<int> a` just creates an object but does not return anything, while `vector<int>()` returns the "anonymous" new object.

Try:

```
return vector<int>();
```

Comment: You posted this as an answer but it sounds like you're not really providing an answer.  Did you mean to post a comment?

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```cpp
return {};
```

This will create a anonymous object.